# Is there a way to know I am getting the last element in the foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net

I need to do special treatment for the last element in the collection. I am wondering if I can know I hit the last element when using foreach loop.

Comment: is there a reason you don't use `for`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only way I know of is to increment a counter and compare with length on exit, or when breaking out of loop set a boolean flag, `loopExitedEarly`.

Comment: which sort of defeats the purpose of foreach

Comment: Yes, sometimes I convert to a traditional loop if the intention is clearer

Comment: `increase a counter and compare with length...`, that's exactly a `for` loop.

Comment: @Danny Chen: where do I say it isn't?

Comment: If you have know the length (e.g. you don't just have an enumerator), you don't need to break early or set any flags, you just say `if (currentCount++ == container.Count) { /* last element */ }`

Comment: @Mud: sure, but that means you have to perform that test each time through the loop.

Comment: @Mitch: And? If you *don't* perform that test, then you don't know when you're at the last element such that you can "do special treatment" of it. The best you can do is specialized *post* processing of the last element, *in addition* to the normal case processing. Also, the OP didn't say "last *visited* element", he said "last element in the collection". Using an enumerator directly (as I showed below) is the broadest solution; no requirement that the container have a Count method, or that you even have access to the container.

Comment: @Mud: you seem to be missing the point. Rather than perform the test each time through the loop. increment a counter and test ONCE outside the loop. For small loops, it makes little difference. BUT if you had 10,000 items, maybe it would be significant. Admitted it does require a container to provide a Count, but what container doesn't?

Comment: Did you not read my post? Test *what* outside the loop? If you don't test it *in* the loop, then the last element is going to receive normal processing. All you can do *after* the loop is provide *additional* processing. Also "maybe would be significant" is just that... a maybe. Unless you've identified this code (via testing) as a performance bottleneck, the goal should be code that most clearly expresses your intent. *"More computing sins are committed in the name of efficiency (without necessarily achieving it) than for any other single reason - including blind stupidity."* - W.A. Wulf

Comment: "Admitted it does require a container to provide a Count, but what container doesn't?"  Who says you even have a container? What if the code receives only an enumerator, which provides much better decoupling? Just as with writing generics (perhaps more in C++, where generics are a lot more flexible), every additional operator/method you use restricts the generality of the code.

Comment: @Mud: " every additional operator/method you use restricts the generality of the code" - yeah, I've seen lots of that highly generic code, and many times its so complicated that only a language lawyer (less then 1% of practioners) can understand it! :)

Comment: Huh? I'm talking about the difference between choosing `!=` or `<` in a loop test. No difference in code complexity, but the latter places an additional requirement on `T` that the former doesn't. My point is simply that there's no need to require access to the original container, or to require that that container have a `Count` member, unless there's some appreciable gain. I don't see what that gain is here.

Comment: "if you had 10,000 items, maybe it would be significant"  I tested it on my (very old, slow) machine, and the difference is a 6 *microseconds*.

Comment: @Mud: Your right.  I misread the question. Suggest OP unmarks as accepted, so I can delete.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a *direct* way. You'll have to keep buffering the next element.

```
IEnumerable<Foo> foos = ...

Foo prevFoo = default(Foo);
bool elementSeen = false;

foreach (Foo foo in foos)
{
    if (elementSeen) // If prevFoo is not the last item...
        ProcessNormalItem(prevFoo);

    elementSeen = true;
    prevFoo = foo;
}

if (elementSeen) // Required because foos might be empty.
    ProcessLastItem(prevFoo);
```

Alternatively, you could use the underlying enumerator to do the same thing:

```
using (var erator = foos.GetEnumerator())
{
    if (!erator.MoveNext())
        return;

    Foo current = erator.Current;

    while (erator.MoveNext())
    {
        ProcessNormalItem(current);
        current = erator.Current;
    }

    ProcessLastItem(current);
}
```

It's a lot easier when working with collections that reveal how many elements they have (typically the `Count` property from `ICollection` or `ICollection<T>`) - you can maintain a counter (alternatively, if the collection exposes an indexer, you could use a for-loop instead):

```
int numItemsSeen = 0;

foreach(Foo foo in foos)
{
   if(++numItemsSeen == foos.Count)
       ProcessLastItem(foo)

   else ProcessNormalItem(foo);
}
```

If you can use [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/), it's easy:

```
foreach (var entry in foos.AsSmartEnumerable())
{
    if(entry.IsLast)
       ProcessLastItem(entry.Value)

    else ProcessNormalItem(entry.Value);
}
```

If efficiency isn't a concern, you could do:

```
Foo[] fooArray = foos.ToArray();

foreach(Foo foo in fooArray.Take(fooArray.Length - 1))
    ProcessNormalItem(foo);

ProcessLastItem(fooArray.Last());
```

Comment: `AsSmartEnumerable()` is part of Jon Skeet's MiscUtil. Are you sure it's in MoreLinq too? https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/search?q=AsSmartEnumerable&unscoped_q=AsSmartEnumerable

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not, I would write it with a for loop like:

```
string[] names = { "John", "Mary", "Stephanie", "David" };
int iLast = names.Length - 1;
for (int i = 0; i <= iLast; i++) {
    Debug.Write(names[i]);
    Debug.Write(i < iLast ? ", " : Environment.NewLine);
}
```

And yes, I know about String.Join :).

---

I see others already posted similar ideas while I was typing mine, but I'll post it anyway:

```
void Enumerate<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T, bool> action) {
    IEnumerator<T> enumerator = items.GetEnumerator();
    if (!enumerator.MoveNext()) return;
    bool foundNext;
    do {
        T item = enumerator.Current;
        foundNext = enumerator.MoveNext();
        action(item, !foundNext);
    }
    while (foundNext);
}
```

...

```
string[] names = { "John", "Mary", "Stephanie", "David" };
Enumerate(names, (name, isLast) => {
    Debug.Write(name);
    Debug.Write(!isLast ? ", " : Environment.NewLine);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<int> numbers = new ....;
int last = numbers.Last();

Stack<int> stack = new ...;
stack.Peek();
```

update

```
    var numbers = new int[] { 1, 2,3,4,5 };

    var enumerator = numbers.GetEnumerator();
    object last = null;
    bool hasElement = true;

    do
    {
        hasElement = enumerator.MoveNext();

        if (hasElement)
        {
            last = enumerator.Current;
            Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current);
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Last = {0}", last);

    } while (hasElement);

    Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

Not without jumping through flaming hoops (see above). But you can just use the enumerator directly (slightly awkward because of C#'s enumerator design):

```
  IEnumerator<string> it = foo.GetEnumerator();
  for (bool hasNext = it.MoveNext(); hasNext; ) {
     string element = it.Current;
     hasNext = it.MoveNext();

     if (hasNext) { // normal processing
        Console.Out.WriteLine(element);
     } else { // special case processing for last element
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Last but not least, " + element);
     }
  }
```

Notes on the other approaches I see here: Mitch's approach requires having access to a container which exposes it's size.  J.D.'s approach requires writing a method in advance, then doing your processing via a closure.  Ani's approach spreads loop management all over the place. John K's approach involves creating numerous additional objects, or (second method) only allows *additional post processing* of the last element, rather than special case processing.

I don't understand why people don't use the Enumerator directly in a normal loop, as I've shown here. [K.I.S.S.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

This is cleaner with Java iterators, because their interface uses `hasNext` rather than `MoveNext`. You could easily write an extension method for IEnumerable that gave you Java-style iterators, but that's overkill unless you write this kind of loop a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Is it Special treatment can be done only while processing on the foreach loop, Is it you can't do that while adding to the collection. If this is your case, have your own custom collection,

```
 public class ListCollection : List<string>
    {
        string _lastitem;

        public void Add(string item)
        {
            //TODO: Do  special treatment on the new Item, new item should be last one.
            //Not applicable for filter/sort
             base.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Deferred Execution trick

Build a class that encapsulates the values to be processed and the processing function for deferred execution purpose.   We will end up using one instance of it for each element processed in the loop.

```
// functor class
class Runner {
    string ArgString {get;set;}
    object ArgContext {get;set;}

    // CTOR: encapsulate args and a context to run them in
    public Runner(string str, object context) {
        ArgString = str;
        ArgContext = context;
    }

    // This is the item processor logic. 
    public void Process() {
        // process ArgString normally in ArgContext
    }
}
```

Use your functor in the `foreach` loop to effect deferred execution by one element:

```
// intended to track previous item in the loop
var recent = default(Runner); // see Runner class above

// normal foreach iteration
foreach(var str in listStrings) {
    // is deferred because this executes recent item instead of current item
    if (recent != null)
        recent.Process(); // run recent processing (from previous iteration)

    // store the current item for next iteration
    recent = new Runner(str, context);
}

// now the final item remains unprocessed - you have a choice
if (want_to_process_normally)
    recent.Process(); // just like the others
else
    do_something_else_with(recent.ArgString, recent.ArgContext);
```

This functor approach uses memory more but prevents you from having to count the elements in advance. In some scenarios you might achieve a kind of efficiency.

- OR

### Shorter Workaround

If you want to apply special processing to the last element after processing them all in a regular way ....

```
// example using strings
var recentStr = default(string);

foreach(var str in listStrings) {
    recentStr = str;
    // process str normally
}

// now apply additional special processing to recentStr (last)
```

It's a potential workaround.

Comment: I like this answer as generally works over *any* IEnumerator -- something that `for(;;)` and an index may not do well/at all (it also doesn't require a `Count()`). How about if the way the last string is processed is not compatible with other processing though? (E.g. is there a "good" way to re-write this with a 1-look ahead?)

Comment: I updated the my answer with another scenario that uses deferred execution to achieve something as good as a look ahead without having to use count or iterate the collection a second time.

Comment: @Mitch. The deferred execution I'm definitely not recommending be used normally or often, but it might be a useful approach to some edge cases. Worth noting here as an extra tool in the arsenal. The second suggestion is more viable but it's only for an edge case too.  This shall be the edge case answer.  Or some code acrobatics.  :)